# Decimal Value error

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that grabs 2 inputs from the user: 1) the price of an item 2) the amount payed. It will then return the difference of the two (change due) and it will then compute how many bills and coins would be given back. I'm having trouble when finding the decimal (coin values accurately):

```
int one, five, ten, twenty,qs, ds, ns, ps, rem ;
    double price, pay,change;
    String user;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Price: $");
        price = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("From: $");
        pay = input.nextDouble();
        change = pay - price;


        twenty =  (int) (change / 20.00);
        rem =  (int) (change % 20.00);
        ten =  (int) (rem / 10.00);
        rem =  (int) (rem % 10.00);
        five =  (int) (rem / 5.00);
        rem =  (int) (rem % 5.00);
        one =  (int) (rem);
        //
        qs = (int) rem / 25;
        rem = (int) rem % 25;
        ds = (int) rem / 10;
        rem = (int) rem % 10;
        ns = (int) rem / 5;
        rem = (int) rem % 5;
        ps = (int) rem;
        System.out.println("Computed change: $" + change);
        System.out.println(twenty + " x $20 bills, \n" + ten
                + " x $10 bills, \n" + five + " x $5 bills, \n" + one
                + " x $1 bills, \n" + qs + " x 25c coins \n" + ds
                + " x 10c coins \n" + ns + " x 5c coins \n" + ps
                + " x 1c coins \n");

        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another "
                + "quantity? (Y or N):");
        input.nextLine();
        user = input.nextLine();

        if (!user.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    } while (user.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    input.close();
    // System.exit(0);
```

I'm almost sure the problem lies in casting the value of the remainder as an int, which would discard any value after the decimal point. I've tried dividng and modulo operation with .25, .10, .5, .1 but that doesn't seem to work. There is something I'm not seeing.

Comment: Before we go on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: you can use BigDecimal instead of double and use remainder..

Comment: Thanks, really helpful link as well as @nachokk comment. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the price in cents, this way you can avoid using decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `double` or `float` for currency as their precision is not perfect. You might want to convert the entire number as a `Long` representing the cents, then format to output the decimal. That way, your math calculus will be decimal free.

Something like

```
Long price = Long.parseLong(input.nextLine().replace(",", ""));
NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US); 
String s = n.format(price / 100.0);
System.out.println(s);
```

Now, you should be able to easily resolve your issue.

Comment: Would you say using long is a quicker way to write the program. Or should I consider using the BigDecimal class instead?

Comment: @LuisFelipe I would still prefer using `Long` as it will be easier for you if you have any math to do on the value.

Comment: @LuisFelipe I got no feedback, did this answer works for you ?